# Is it possible to reduce the font-size on a `<span>` based on its content?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<span>` element including a long text. The span has a font-size set on its css stype. The text will be overflowed or wrapped if it is too long. I wonder whether there is a css style to make the text fit into the width of the `span` without wrapping. I want the css style to disable the `font-size` on the `span` and automatically apply a new font-size to fix the content.

Comment: Is it okay to implement it using a custom function with jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: It is ok if there is no automatical way

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the case, but if your `<span>`'s width is dependent on the width or height of the viewport, you can use `vw` or `vh` CSS units.
[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Comment: I want to adjust the font size of the span automatically in case the text is too long